# How to add jaxb binding when creating SOAP webservice stubs using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, jaxb

I have some conflicts from a wsdl that another company wrote, but I should be able to correct them with a custom jaxb binding file.

When I go to create a new Web Service Client, I don't see how to do this.

Another option is just to do everything by hand, but the fact that Eclipse takes care of the classpaths is why I would prefer not to go this route.